# How to get LOG when install ios app?

Tags: ios, debugging, logging, installation

I trying use **Over The Air (OTA)** iOS `IPA` File Distribution to install `IPA` file for iphone but it have error.

So that I need **get log** from when I click the install link to the dialog error show.

Please show me the tool or a method to get log install.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

System logs show info about installation process. To see operating system logs from device you should connect you iphone/ipad to your computer. Then choose in XCode Window > Devices, and select you connected device from list on the left. If console with logs is hidden you can open it by clicking this icon:

[image]